# Adding a SlingFilter to Apache Felix configMgr

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I'm writing a simple Sling filter to run on AEM 5.6.1.  I've made the filter use configuration properties, and I would have expected it to show up in /system/console/configMgr but it does not.

```
@SlingFilter(generateComponent = true, generateService = true, order = -700, scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST)
public class SimpleFilter implements Filter {

    @Property(value = "property.defaultvalue")
    private static final String PROPERTY_KEY = "property.key";

    private String configuredValue;

    @Activate
    protected void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> config = (Map<String, String>) componentContext.getProperties();
        this.configuredValue = config.get(PROPERTY_KEY);
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(this.configuredValue);
    }
}
```

I'm able to install the bundle, see that the filter is working and can find it in /system/console/bundles, but it doesn't get added to /system/console/configMgr like I thought it would from the presense of the @Property annotation. Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `metatype = true` along with the `generateComponent` if you need to configurations to appear in the configuration manager. By default metatype is false.

```
@SlingFilter(generateComponent = true, 
    generateService = true, 
    metatype = true,
    order = -700, 
    scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST)
```

Refer [Apache Felix - SCR Annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html#component) and [Apache Felix Metatype Service](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-metatype-service.html) to understand it better.